# How to setup a push notification Listener/reciever in python to recieve File Changes

Tags: python, rest, push-notification, google-drive-api

I have been trying to utilize Google Drive's `REST` API to recieve file changes as push notifications, but I have no idea on where to start. As I am new to programming all together, I am unable to find any solutions.

I am using Python to develop my code, and the script that I am writing is to monitor any changes in any given spreadsheet to run some operations on then modified spreadsheet data.

Considering I was able to set up the Sheets and Drive (`readonly`) APIs properly, I am confident that given some direction, I would be able to setup this notification reciever/listener as well.

Here is Google Drive API Feature [Page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the guide in [Detect Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes)

> For Google Drive apps that need to keep track of changes to files, the
>   Changes collection provides an efficient way to detect changes to all
>   files, including those that have been shared with a user. The
>   collection works by providing the current state of each file, if and
>   only if the file has changed since a given point in time.
>
> Retrieving changes requires a pageToken to indicate a point in time to
>   fetch changes from.

There's a [github code demo](https://github.com/googlearchive/drive-pushnotifications-playground) that you can test and base your project on.